# How to solve the "Error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Kindly help me fix the Error " Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index. Herewith is my code. Thank you

```
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim index1 As Integer
    index1 = e.RowIndex + 1
    //the error was here
    index = GridView1.DataKeys(index1).Values(0)
    index = Convert.ToInt32(index)
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("DELETE from tblauditplan WHERE AuditArea = @auditarea")
            Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@auditplan", index)
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()


            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Me.BindGrid()
End Sub
```

Comment: use debugger and figure it out.

Comment: your code doesnt check to see if there are enough rows before `index1 = e.RowIndex + 1`

Comment: Thank you for the comment Plutonix and T McKeown. I'll try your suggestion/comment.

Comment: Pluonix and T McKeown

the error was pointing in this portion with the same error
Here is the code
Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Values(0))

Comment: The error message is telling you that you are using an invalid index.  Have you actually looked to see what the index is when the exception is thrown and then investigated where that value comes from?  You have an IDE with a debugger so you should learn how to use it.  Even if you're not up to using breakpoints you can still throw in `MessageBox.Show` calls or the like, which is how most people debug to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim index As Integer
Dim index1 As Integer
index1 = e.RowIndex + 1
//the error was here
index = GridView1.DataKeys(index1).Values(0)
index = Convert.ToInt32(index)
```

??
Why not just

```
index = GridView1.DataKeys(e.rowindex + 1).Values(0)
```

but yeah, you need to put in a check to make sure that you're not at the end of the rows.

```
if not index > e.rowCount
```

or something like that, without knowing what "e" is.